# How to build a form which has different input data depending on where the form was called in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using a offer model to save offer details into the database.

My offer looks like this:

```
class Offer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :clerk, optional: true
end
```

The order **_index.html.erb** partial gets rendered on both, the **show.html.erb** view for companies and the **show.html.erb** view for products. On the bottom of the order **_index.html.erb** partial there is a button to create a new offer:

```
<% if @company %>
  <%= link_to 'new offer', new_offer_path(@company, @offer, :source => "company"), :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
<% elsif @product %>
  <%= link_to 'new offer', new_offer_path(@product, @offer, :source => "product"), :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Im saving to the *source* param to identify in the controller on which page the user clicked on the button.

To handle those different requirements i build two different forms which get rendered in my **new.html.erb**

```
<% if params[:source] == "company" || params[:product_id].nil? %>
    <%= render 'form_from_company', offer: @offer, company: @company %>
    <%= link_to 'Zurück', company_path(@company), :class => "btn btn-secondary" %>
<% elsif params[:source] == "product"%>
    <%= render 'form_from_product', offer: @offer, product: @product %>
    <%= link_to 'Zurück', product_path(@product), :class => "btn btn-secondary" %>
<% end %>
```

My form look like this (form_from_company):

```
<%= simple_form_for [@offer] do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :company_id, @company.id %>
  <%= f.association :product, prompt: "Produkt auswählen", label_method: :name_and_product_autocomplete, input_html: {id: 'dropdown-choice-select'} %>
  <%= f.association :clerk, label_method: :full_name, collection: Clerk.where(company_id: @company.id), prompt: "Mitarbeiter auswählen" %>
...
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

My other form look like this (form_from_product):

```
<%= simple_form_for [@offer] do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :product_id, @product.id %>
  <%= f.association :company, prompt: "Firma auswählen", label_method: :name_and_company_autocomplete, input_html: {id: 'dropdown-choice-select'}%>
...
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

i even got it to work like this but only for correct input.
So if the user enters wrong data which doesnt get validated, the new form gets rendered again to show him what he is missing and here is my problem.

After he presses the submit button for the first time, there is no params[:source] included and it just shows the "empty" new page, since the forms only get rendered when there is the params[:source]

I feel like there should be a better solution but i dont know how to do it the right way.

Can someone give me a hint or a link on how to handle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is adding the source as a `hidden_field` in both the forms:

```rb
<%= simple_form_for [@offer] do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :source, value: 'company' %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :company_id, @company.id %>
  <%= f.association :product, prompt: "Produkt auswählen", label_method: :name_and_product_autocomplete, input_html: {id: 'dropdown-choice-select'} %>
  <%= f.association :clerk, label_method: :full_name, collection: Clerk.where(company_id: @company.id), prompt: "Mitarbeiter auswählen" %>
...
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

```rb
<%= simple_form_for [@offer] do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :source, value: 'product' %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :product_id, @product.id %>
  <%= f.association :company, prompt: "Firma auswählen", label_method: :name_and_company_autocomplete, input_html: {id: 'dropdown-choice-select'}%>
...
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

This way you will have access to the params[:source] and your problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you Hackerman, this solved my problem.